# Lorentz Covariance of the law $\mathbf{\vec{F}} = \frac{d\mathbf{\vec{p}}}{dt}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, forces, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

This is the force law as seen in some frame $S$:

$$\mathbf{\vec{F}} = [\gamma_v^3 ma_x, \gamma_v ma_y, \gamma_v ma_z]$$

How do I Lorentz transform it to:

$$\mathbf{\vec{F}'} = [\gamma_v'^3 ma_x', \gamma_v' ma_y', \gamma_v' ma_z']$$

in a frame $S'$ moving at speed $w$ in the $x$ direction with respect to the frame $S$?

The force transformations being:

$$\mathbf{\vec{F}'} = [F_x - \frac{w/c^2(F_y v_y + F_z v_z)}{1 - wv_x/c^2}, \frac{F_y}{\gamma_w (1 - wv_x/c^2)}, \frac{F_z}{\gamma_w (1 - wv_x/c^2)}]$$

The gamma being:

$$\gamma_v' = (1 - \frac{(\frac{v_x - w}{1 - wv_x/c^2})^{2} + v_y^2 + v_z^2}{c^2})^{-1/2}$$
$$\gamma_v = (1 - \frac{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}{c^2})^{-1/2}$$

The acceleration transformations being:

$$\mathbf{\vec{a}'} = [\frac{a_x}{\gamma_w^3(1 - wv_x/c^2)^3}, \frac{a_y}{\gamma_w^2(1 - wv_x/c^2)^2} + \frac{a_x \frac{wv_y}{c^2}}{\gamma_w^2(1 - wv_x/c^2)^3}, \frac{a_z}{\gamma_w^2(1 - wv_x/c^2)^2} + \frac{a_x \frac{wv_z}{c^2}}{\gamma_w^2(1 - wv_x/c^2)^3}]$$

Comment: How do you Lorentz transform any vector?

Comment: The algebra gets too tedious. If anybody could show me the way..

Comment: Is the question unclear or not useful?

Comment: The Lorentz Transformation relates 4-vectors. On the other hand invariance refers to scalars, not to equations or 4-vectors. So there is no meaning to the Lorentz invariance of an equation with 3-vectors. I think that what do you want to say is about the Lorentz covariance of the   equation
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}=\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf{P} }{\!\!\!\mathrm d \tau}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathbf{F}$ = the force 4-vector, $\mathbf{P}$ = the linear momentum 4-vector and $\:\tau$ = the invariant proper time scalar.

Comment: If $\:\mathbf{f}\:$ is the force 3-vector, like the Lorentz force, applied on a particle of rest mass $\:m_{o}\:$ moving with velocity 3-vector $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\:$, then the force 4-vector is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}=\left(\gamma_{\upsilon} \mathbf{f} , \gamma_{\upsilon}\dfrac{ \mathbf{f}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{c}\right), \quad \gamma_{\upsilon}=\left(1-\dfrac{\upsilon^2}{c^2}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}1/2}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

Comment: @Frobenius Yeah that's true. But so is this: $$\mathbf{F} = \frac{d\mathbf{P}}{d\tau}$$ can be split into two separate equations, out of which one is $$\mathbf{\vec{F}} = 
 \frac{d\mathbf{\vec{p}}}{dt}$$

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast:  The point Frobenius was trying to make (I think) is that you can't transform the three spatial components of $\vec{\mathbf{F}}$ into another frame without knowing the time component, any more than you can transform an event's coordinates $(x,y,z)$ into another frame without knowing $t$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little trick: if you write
$$
\mathbf{F}' = \frac{d\mathbf{p'}}{dt'} = 
\frac{d\mathbf{p'}}{dt}{\Big/}\frac{dt'}{dt}
$$
then
$$
F'_x=\frac{dp_x'}{dt}{\Big/}\frac{dt'}{dt}\quad 
F'_x=\frac{dp_y}{dt}{\Big/}\frac{dt'}{dt} \quad
F'_x=\frac{dp_z}{dt}{\Big/}\frac{dt'}{dt}
$$
where I have used that for a boost along the $x$ direction $p_y'=p_y$ and $p_z'=p_z$. At this point you've just to do *two* derivatives
$$
\frac{dp_x'}{dt} = 
\frac{d}{dt}\Big[\gamma(w)\left(p_x-\frac{w}{c^2}E \right)\Big] =
\gamma(w)\left(\frac{dp_x}{dt} -\frac{w}{c^2}\frac{dE}{dt}\right) =
\gamma(w)\left(F_x -\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)
$$
where I used that $dE/dt=\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ (you can use the *mass shell* relation to prove it), and
$$
\frac{dt'}{dt} = 
\frac{d}{dt}\Big[\gamma(w)\left(t-\frac{wx}{c^2}\right)\Big] =
\gamma(w)\left(1-\frac{wv_x}{c^2}\right)
$$
Then finally
$$
F_x' = \frac{F_x-\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{1-\frac{wv_x}{c^2}}
\quad
F_y' = \frac{F_y}{1-\frac{wv_x}{c^2}}
\quad
F_z' = \frac{F_z}{1-\frac{wv_x}{c^2}}
$$
and you may get the relation between the accelerations and so on by explicitly using the expression of the forces.